# Remove Firestore Snapshot Listener From Inside Listener

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Super simple question. I need to remove a firestore snapshot listener once I hit a certain point inside of my listener. Seems like this should be super easy but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Example code:

```
val registration = gameRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
     //code....

     //if(condition is meet){
     //    destroy this listener
     //}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "once I hit a certain point inside of my listener" ? can you also paste the code where you want to delete your listener?

Comment: I posted an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume that the listener is returned immediately and that its callback won't be invoked until after it's returned by the function:

```
var feedback: ListenerRegistration? = null
feedback = gameRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
    feedback?.remove()
}
```

Comment: I know. I can't call registration.remove() from inside registration

Comment: how about making an interface that knows when its inside the listener and if that success just call the registration.remove() outside registration

Comment: I tried calling a function outside of registration to remove it but I couldn't call the function from that scope

Comment: Edited my answer so that it satisfies the compiler.

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know i would find a question for this, thank you

Comment: Why isn't this on the official docs?